# quadrature formula for a lune

Tags: complex-analysis, euclidean-geometry

I have been reading about [quadrature formulas](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0487) in the complex plane.

On the set $\mathbb{D} = \{|z| < 1\}$ we have $\int_{\mathbb{D}} f(z) dA = \pi f(0)$.  Standard result in Harmonic functions.

The sample paper shows for the [limaçon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on), $\Omega = \{ z + \frac{1}{2}z^2: |z| < 1\} $ we have $\int_{\mathbb{D}} f(z) dA = \frac{3\pi}{2} f(0) + \frac{\pi}{2} f'(0)$.

---

**Does a quadrature formula exist for the [lune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_%28mathematics%29)?** Let $f(z)$ be an holomorphic function (on a large enough area). 
Given a lune shape (such as) $L=\big\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-1|<\frac{3}{4},\;|z|>1\big\} $ is there a formula for $\int_L f(z) \, dA$ that is a linear combination of $f(z)$ and it's derivatives evaluated at specific points?

For more information on quadrature formulas, here is an article [Topology of Quadrature Domains](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0487).

[image]

Comment: are you certain that the picture matches with the formula ?

Comment: @mercio I have re-written the equation.  Look any better?

Answer (score 0):

In standard Euclidean geometry there is a formula which is in the paper (pdf) "The Five Quadrable Lunes" by Brian J. Shelburne.